# Assign associative arrays to php variable

Tags: php, associative-array

i have an array

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => phizy [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [username] => rapik [id] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [username] => asas [id] => 5 ) )

how do i extract and put them in php variables?

> ```
> <li><?php $username." with id of ".$userid."</li>";
> ```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to turn all the keys of an array into variables, you can use the [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
foreach($array as $arobj)
{
    ?>
    <li><?php $arobj['username']." with id of ".$arobj['id']; ?></li>
    <?php
}
```

or, if you want to assign to the variable then,

```
foreach($array as $arobj)
{
    $username =  $arobj['username'];
    $userid = $arobj['id'];
    ?>
    <li><?php $username." with id of ".$userid; ?></li>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: `<li><?php echo $username." with id of ".$userid; ?></li>` (good answer just missed out the echo)

Comment: You can leave out the `echo` if you write it as `<?=` instead of `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

Just *for fun*, if you **have to** assign variables base on array key, you can try this:

```php
foreach($array as $subArr)
{
  foreach($subArr as $key=>$value)
  {
    $$key=$value;
  }
  echo "<li>$username with id of $id.</li>";
}
```

[Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)